# why the spectrum of an operator with compact resolvent is discrete

Tags: functional-analysis

I want a proof of this proposition:

"The spectrum of an operator with compact resolvent is discrete"???

Thank you very much

Comment: @Eric Auld:  I have no idea

Comment: To start with you should know the following property of compact operators.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal: what property?

Comment: @mario: The spectrum of a compact operator in the shaded area.

Comment: @Mhenni Benghorbal: I don't understand you

Comment: @mario: The propert is "What kind of spectrum does a compact operator have?" I gave you the link to see this property.

Answer (score 0):

Is $T$ is a self adjoint operator with compact resolvent then:

(a) either $\sigma(T)= \Phi$
(b) or  $\sigma(T)={\lambda_n , n\ge{1}}$ such that $limit |\lambda_n |= +\infty$
Furthermore, there exists $\lambda_0 \in\rho(T)$ such that $|\lambda_1 - \lambda_0| \le  |\lambda_2 - \lambda_0| \le ... $

$ker(T-\lambda_n)$ is of finite dimension and we notice that the elements of the spectrum of $T$ is a sequence so all the points are isolated, thus $\sigma(T)=\sigma_d(T)$

Comment: This is not a proof, which is what the question asks for.